# Regex substring in python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to identify a sub string from any string based on a regular expression in Python3.

For Example, take the following strings:

```
It sent a notice of delivery of goods: UserName1
Sent a notice of delivery of the goods: User is not found, UserName2
It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: UserName1
It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: User is not found, UserName2
```

I want to get the text after colon

**Result:**

```
UserName1
User is not found, UserName2
UserName1
User is not found, UserName2
```

I ask help in writing a regular expression.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You did not have tryied anything. I would suggest to you to look first at -> docs.python.org/2/library/re.html . Then try to build an regex. If you have problems with the regex show us your regex an the community will help you. Here is an example how regex in python works: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Comment: why not str.split(':') and avoiding the regex altogether

Comment: I would rather go with [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and string slicing, no need to split on every ':'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for regex here, you can just `split` the text on `\n` and `:` , i.e..:

```
text =  """It sent a notice of delivery of goods: UserName1
Sent a notice of delivery of the goods: User is not found, UserName2
It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: UserName1
It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: User is not found, UserName2"""

for x in text.split("\n"):
    print(x.split(": ")[1])
```

---

If you prefer a regex, and to avoid multiple `:` on the line, you can use:

```
for x in text.split("\n"):
    print(re.split(".*: ", x)[1])
```

---

Output:

```
UserName1
User is not found, UserName2
UserName1
User is not found, UserName2
```

Comment: This truncates the output, if multiple ':' exist per line

Comment: The example provided by the OP doesn't contain multiple `:` , my answer is based on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
S[S.find(':') + 1:].strip()
```

or if you need the last occurrence of ':'

```
S[S.rfind(':') + 1:].strip()
```